# How do I cache data from sqlite to listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, caching

Hi guys I have an activity which extends ListActivity and displays a listview which is populated from my SQLite DB table.

Each entry in my listview has a the same background file as part of my GUI design.
Problem is that the scrolling in my listview is very laggy. I think that is because each listview entry is being created "on the fly" which causes the laggines.

Can you please look at my code and tell me how can I cache it for better results? Or maybe there is another solution?

CODE:

```
package android.GUI;


public class Shifts extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener,
    SimpleGestureListener {

private Typeface tf = Entry.tf, tf2 = Entry.tf2;
public static int count = 1;
int dbHourTime = 0;
private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
public static DBAdapter DB;
public static Cursor cursor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.shifts);

    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);

    DB = new DBAdapter(this);
    DB.open();

    String[] columns = new String[] { DB.KEY_DATE, DB.KEY_HOURS,
            DB.KEY_DAY, DB.KEY_ROWID, DB.KEY_START, DB.KEY_END };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.dateDisp, R.id.shiftDisp, R.id.day,
            R.id.rawId, R.id.start, R.id.finish };
    new cursorLoad().execute("this");

    TextView SF = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
    SF.setTypeface(tf);

    TextView sum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sum);
    sum.setTypeface(tf);

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_entry, cursor, columns, to);
    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_shifts_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.back:

        finish();
        return true;
    case R.id.clear:
        DBAdapter DB = new DBAdapter(this);
        DB.open();
        DB.deleteAll();
        startActivity(getIntent());
        finish();

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSwipe(int direction) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    switch (direction) {

    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:

        intent.setClass(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT:

        intent.setClass(this, Entry.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN:

        break;
    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP:

        break;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}

@Override
public void onDoubleTap() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public class cursorLoad extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        cursor = DB.getAllShifts();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        cursor.moveToLast();
        count = cursor.getPosition();
        int g = count;

        cursor.moveToNext();
        return null;
    }

}

 }
```

Comment: hm, you are creating a `SimpleCursorAdapter` based on the `cursor` attribute - that is set by an `AsyncTask` started in `#onCreate(..)` - that's not a very *reliable* design.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. care to explain why? (I'm new to java\android so would really like to know more)

Comment: Since an async task executes on a separate thread (in a thread pool) - there's no real guarantee that you're not creating the SimpleCursorAdapter with `null` in the `cursor` field (since it's first assigned in the `#doInBackground()` of your async task).

Comment: Got it, so is there any conzenous on what code you put in a #doInBackground when using in a listview\listActivity class?

and can you also explain to me how to cache data from my DB so it will run smoother?

Comment: OK, I believe what I'm looking for is a hashtable to keep my entries.
But since my listview entries are dynamically added by the user, how can I set the table to add keys dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end what I needed was the ViewHolder class along with getView\bindView.